# How to make FullCalendar to display only select month and date

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

in FullCalendar by default it show current month,date  and year but i want custom 
like 5 jun 2013  .

how to do this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();


    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        theme: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: false,
        events: [
            {
                title: 'Movie In',
                start: new Date(y, m, d),
                end: new Date(y, m,d),
                allDay: true,
            },

            ],
        eventColor: '#E42217'
    });

});
```

in

> var d = '5';
>   var m = '7';
>   var y = '2013';

i have pass custom date month also but not working

thanks

Comment: just i want march (whatever) month (not current month )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want: [gotoDate](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/current_date/gotoDate/)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the Column Header, Use columnFormat like this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    theme: true,
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: false,
    events: [
        {
            title: 'Movie In',
            start: new Date(y, m, d),
            end: new Date(y, m,d),
            allDay: true,
        },

        ],
    eventColor: '#E42217',
    columnFormat: {
                  month: 'ddd',    // Mon
                  week: 'ddd M/d', // Mon 9/7
                  day: 'dd MMM yyyy' 
                  }
});
```

If you want to go for particular date, use this method.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', year [, month, [ date ]] )
```

Once initialized the calendar, call this method.

Comment: not for header . on page load time  calender show current date, month , but i want custom like i set ini date time 12/08/2013 then its show date of aug month .. not current .

Comment: i dont want change columnFormat .. just i want show by default march of this month not jan .

Comment: then use this method: $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', year [, month, [ date ]] ) Ex: $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', 2013,3,10 )

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultDate:$.now(),
            // lang: 'ja',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true,
            customButtons: {
                btnJan: {
                    text: 'January',
                    click: function() {
                        var moment = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
                        var currentMonth =  moment.format('YYYY')+'-'+01+'-'+01;
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', currentMonth);
                    }
                },
                btnFeb: {
                    text: 'February',
                    click: function() {
                        var moment = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
                        var currentMonth =  moment.format('YYYY')+'-'+02+'-'+01;
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', currentMonth);
                    }
                }
            },
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today btnJan btnFeb',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            dayNamesShort: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday','Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
            monthNames:['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July','August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
            titleFormat:'MMMM D YYYY',
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: '2016-06-01'
                }
            ]
        });
});
```

**Reference:** https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/getDate/
**Demo** http://www.somelesson.blogspot.com/2016/11/fullcalendar-javascript-event-calendar.html
**Output:**
[image]